# How Do I Properly Use a "throws clause" in Java?

Tags: java, simulator, dice, clause, throws

I'm still new to programming and I know that the code I have below is probably a mess but, how do I properly use a "throws clause"? I'm supposed to use it for an assignment(add a throws clause to the main method header) but when I try to run it,

I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
    Syntax error on token "throws", delete this token.

What am I doing wrong? I'm also supposed to print mean and standard deviation to an output file, using a three decimal format, however, I don't understand how to go about that either.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class DiceSimulation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER = 10000; // the number of times to roll the dice

        Random generator = new Random();
        File myFile = new File("Results");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Results")throws::IOException;
        outputFile.println("FileChooser.txt");
        outputFile.println("Filereader.txt");
        outputFile.println("FileWriter.txt");
        outputFile.close();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int die1Value; // number of spots on the first die
        int die2Value; // number of spots on the second die
        int count = 0; // number of times the dice were rolled
        int snakeEyes = 0; // number of times snake eyes is rolled
        int twos = 0; // number of times double two is rolled
        int threes = 0; // number of times double three is rolled
        int fours = 0; // number of times double four is rolled
        int fives = 0; // number of times double five is rolled
        int sixes = 0; // number of times double six is rolled

        do {
            new Random();
            System.out.println("You rolled: ");
            die1Value = keyboard.nextInt();

            new Random();
            System.out.println("You rolled: ");
            die2Value = keyboard.nextInt();

        } while (count <= 0);

        if (die1Value == 1)
            ;
        {
            ++snakeEyes;
        }
        if (die1Value == 2)
            ;
        {
            ++twos;
        }
        if (die1Value == 3)
            ;
        {
            ++threes;
        }
        if (die1Value == 4)
            ;
        {
            ++fours;
        }
        if (die1Value == 5)
            ;
        {
            ++fives;
        }
        if (die1Value == 6)
            ;
        {
            ++sixes;
        }
        ++count;
        {

            System.out.println("You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes
                    + " out of " + count + " rolls.");
            System.out.println("You rolled double twos " + twos + " out of "
                    + count + " rolls.");
            System.out.println("You rolled double threes " + threes
                    + " out of " + count + " rolls.");
            System.out.println("You rolled double fours " + fours + " out of "
                    + count + " rolls.");
            System.out.println("You rolled double fives " + fives + " out of "
                    + count + " rolls.");
            System.out.println("You rolled double sixes " + sixes + " out of "
                    + count + " rolls.");
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate assistance, thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you think _add a throws clause to the main method header_ means? And have you looked at what a `throws` clause is?

Comment: Please remove the apologies at the end of your question. They are not relevant.

Comment: It just dawned on me after reading your comment... I feel so dense lol. Thank you though!

Comment: This may seem like I'm being a jerk, but read this:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/  You need a fully fleshed-out discussion of exception handling, not a quick answer.

Comment: What is with your `if`s? They have semi-colons at the end and why do they precede a block-statement???

Comment: I'll take a look at those links. Thank you all very much

Comment: @Sotirios - keep in mind that OP is a beginner and Java does not have header files nor are *method headers* common in the Java venacular. So its easy to understand why he could become confused due to that error message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Results");
```

You don't have to state that a constructor (or any other method for that matter) throws an exception *when calling the constructor (or method)*. We use the `throws` keyword in the method *declaration*, not when actually invoking it. After fixing that, Java will complain that an exception is thrown, You can either:

1. Declare that the `main()` method `throws IOException`
2. Or surround the offending line with a `try/catch` statement

Answer (score 1):

Change your first line to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```